# How can I get a list of all open windows in the command line?

Tags: command-line, window

How can I produce a list of all open windows, including dialog boxes and duplicates, from the command line?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [wmctrl](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) to get a list of all open windows. You will first need to install it.

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

Then you can just run the command.

```
wmctrl -l

0x0080006a -1 localhost panel
0x0180007c  0 localhost Mozilla Firefox
0x02600007  3 localhost user@localhost: /home/user - Shell - Konsole
0x00600011  1 localhost KTorrent
0x02200007  0 localhost user@localhost: /home/user - Shell - Konsole
1           2 3         4
```

The columns:

1. The window ID. This is used for the [#i -i] switch.
2. The desktop ID. It begins counting at 0. -1 means that window is on all desktops. Used with [#d -d] and more.
3. The client machine
4. The name (long title) of the window. Used with [#r -r] mostly, and can be renamed with [#N -N] and [#T -T].

More examples: [wmctrl-examples](http://spiralofhope.com/wmctrl-examples.html)